# Will it be possible to join table with itself

Tags: mysql, sql

Will the result of this queries be able to join without multiplying to each other.

```
Select StudID, StudName, StudYear from tbl_students where StudYear='Third Year';
Select StudID, StudName, StudYear from tbl_students where StudYear='Second Year';
Select StudID, StudName, StudYear from tbl_students where StudYear='First Year';
```

or is it possible the "result" of these queries to be join with 9 columns referring the first 3 columns for the Third Year, second 3 columns for the Second Year and last 3 columns for the First Year.
Thank you for kind answer.

What i have in mind as a result is something like this

```
StudentID   | StudentName   | StudentYear
-----------------------------------------
1           | foo1           |  1
-----------------------------------------
2           | foo2           |  1
-----------------------------------------
3           | foo3           |  2
-----------------------------------------
4           | foo4           |  2
-----------------------------------------
5           | foo5           |  2
-----------------------------------------
6           | foo6           |  3
-----------------------------------------
```

```
StudentID-1   | StudentName-1   | StudentYear-1  |StudentID-2   | StudentName-2   | StudentYear-2 | StudentID-3   | StudentName-3   | StudentYear-3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             | foo1            |  1             | 3            | foo3            |  2             |6             | foo6           | 3       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2             | foo2            |  1             | 4            | foo4            |  2             |              |                |      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              |                 |                | 5            | foo5            |  2             |              |                |       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: What does each row represent? It can't represent a single student. And since it can't, it's not clear what binds the first year student on a given row with the second and third year students. Are you trying to use this to generate a table in a particular layout (one set of columns for each year, with independent rows for each year)? If so, I'd recommend doing that in application logic, not in your query.

Comment: i suggest to move this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/  . and [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61053/how-to-join-two-result-sets-from-same-table-with-different-conditions-on-same-co) might help you

Comment: Please update your question and tell us how you derived the results you've shown. As it is the relationship between the rows in the original table and the rows in the result table appears to be random. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your requirement you must have some id kind of thing to join, so used row number else you will one to many to many resutls

Working in SQL Server. So give it a try in MYSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE #STUDENT(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(10), STUDENT_YEAR INT);
INSERT INTO #STUDENT VALUES(1,'FOO1',1);
INSERT INTO #STUDENT VALUES(2,'FOO2',1);
INSERT INTO #STUDENT VALUES(3,'FOO3',2);
INSERT INTO #STUDENT VALUES(4,'FOO4',2);
INSERT INTO #STUDENT VALUES(5,'FOO5',2);
INSERT INTO #STUDENT VALUES(6,'FOO6',3);


SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S1.ID ASC) RN,
        S1.ID AS [ID_1], S1.NAME AS [NAME_1],S1.STUDENT_YEAR AS [YEAR_1]  
    FROM #STUDENT S1
    where s1.STUDENT_YEAR=1
) T1    
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S2.ID ASC) RN,
        S2.ID AS [ID_2], S2.NAME AS [NAME_2],S2.STUDENT_YEAR AS [YEAR_2]  
    FROM #STUDENT S2
    where s2.STUDENT_YEAR=2
) T2 ON T1.RN = T2.RN
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S3.ID ASC) RN,
        S3.ID AS [ID_3], S3.NAME AS [NAME_3],S3.STUDENT_YEAR AS [YEAR_3]  
    FROM #STUDENT S3
    where s3.STUDENT_YEAR=3
) T3 ON T1.RN = T3.RN
```

**Note** : `#Student` indicates that it is a temporary table.

[image]

Comment: Kudos for making a query that works. The OP did specify the MySQL tag, though.

Comment: i didn't find `full join` and `row_number` in my sql so  just thought some one can understand the logic and can create it in mysql.

Comment: It's not available in MySQL. You have to use a union of two outer joins to simulate full join. Row number can be simulated with a variable, properly initialized and managed throughout the query. It's actually kind of a pain.

Comment: This is possible in Oracle, not MySql.

Answer (score 1):

Ok changed my answer to use subqueries and treat each subquery as a table with its own aliased columns. This does not produce the exact results you wanted this will produce nulls in the other 6 columns that are not filled in. That being said I believe this is about as close are you are going to get to doing what you want in a query.

```
SELECT StudentFirst.*, StudentSecond.*, StudentThird.*
FROM (((tbl_students ts 
left join (SELECT StudID AS StudIDFirst, StudName AS StudNameFirst, StudYear AS StudYearFirst FROM tbl_students WHERE StudYear = 'First Year') AS StudentFirst on (ts.StudID = StudentFirst.StudIDFirst))
left join (SELECT StudID AS StudIDSecond, StudName AS StudNameSecond, StudYear AS StudYearSecond FROM tbl_students WHERE StudYear = 'Second Year') AS StudentSecond on (ts.StudID = StudentSecond.StudIDSecond))
left join (SELECT StudID AS StudIDThird, StudName AS StudNameThird, StudYear AS StudYearThird FROM tbl_students WHERE StudYear ='Third Year') AS StudentThird on (ts.StudID = StudentThird.StudIDThird))
```

Here is the results of the query

[image]

I will say I do not recommend this approach. MySQL has gotten alot better at dealing with subqueries but anything before 5.5 will have horrible performance and even 5.5 won't be great once you get to a certain level of data. Also using your mysql statements to format the results isn't a very good idea either. If you need the results to look a certain way I would retrieve the record set then put them in that format on the front end of a application. I hope this helps.

Comment: Something like that but I'm hoping for the horizontal, not the vertical.

Comment: Sorry didn't think horizontal was a strict requirement. This could be done with subqueries. I will fix my answer when I get home if you still have got a answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort help!. That is EXACTLY what i want to happen.
However it will be really difficult to get the value on the first row knowing that on the other column producing nulls that are not filled in.
I come up to a conclusion that i will just make separated queries for each instance. Great help!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can join those queries together as

```
SELECT * FROM
  (Select StudentID, StudentName, StudentYear as Third_StudYear
     from Students
     where StudentYear=3) y3
  CROSS JOIN (Select StudentID, StudentName, StudentYear as Second_StudYear
                from Students
                where StudentYear=2) y2
  CROSS JOIN (Select StudentID, StudentName, StudentYear as First_StudYear
                from Students
                where StudentYear=1) y1
```

if that's what you really want to do.

Best of luck.

Comment: That query will probably return nothing.

Comment: Now that you've added desired results I can see what you intend, but since I can't see how you're planning on joining things together I've changed this to use a CROSS JOIN, which eliminates the need to understand the joining relationship. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddc8a/5). Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis: You're right on the spot about desired result. However, the rows are repeated to match the column which has the highest no. of row.

Comment: @ZeroSerum - hopefully it will be an instructive exercise for OP.

Comment: Cross join won't do it, it will just multiply the results of y3 with the results of y2, e.g. if y3 has 3 rows and y2 has 2 rows, y3 cross join y2 will return 6 rows, 2 rows from y2 per each row from y3, and cross joining this with y1 will multiply the results even more. I recommend you to avoid using cross join unless you do the proper join in the `WHERE` statement, but that would lead to inner, left or right join...